# Encrypted text inputs alongside shift value results outputs plain text using a Caesar cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

The overall make a script that inputs a line of encrypted text and a distance value and outputs plaintext using a Caesar cipher. 
I have been working on this for the last couple of days but don't understand what i am doing wrong. I feel I am not taking into account the shift value to decode the encrypted text.

```
text = input("Enter plain text: ");
s = input("Shift: ");

def caesar(plainText, shift):
    cipherText = ""
    for char in plainText:
        newChar = ord(char) + shift
        if newChar > 128:
            newChar = newChar % 128
        finalChar = chr(newChar)
        cipherText += finalChar
    return cipherText


print (caesar(text, int(s)));
```

Ive tested with a series of inputs that are supposed to work but only one seems correct

```
Enter plain text: abcde
Shift: 128
abcde
```

This is the only correct Value

```
Enter plain text: EFGHI
Shift: 100
)*+,-
```

Value is supposed to abcde

```
Enter plain text: Khoor#Zruog
Shift: 3
Nkrru&]uxrj
```

Value is supposed to be Hello World

I feel I setup the Shift value incorrect but I am not sure whats wrong exactly.

Comment: To encrypt data, you _shift_ all the values, and to decrypt ciphertext, you should _"unshift"_ all the values and not shift them even further.

Comment: What is the base for your cipher, I don't imagine you are starting from `chr(0)`, this is what is causing your issue in example 2. Use `-3` in your last example and you will get `Hello World`.

Comment: Why are you using `% 128`? This will have a whole range of unprintable characters. What is your target alphabet.